# Свой заголовок Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Есть массив элементов spinner'a

```
 <string-array name="spinner_date">
    <item>Сегодня</item>
    <item>Завтра</item>
    <item>Другой день</item>
</string-array>
```

Как мне при выборе какого-либо элемента массива в spinner'e устанавливать свой заголовок, а не элемент массива? Подробнее, при нажатии я получаю текущую дату и при нажатии на 'Сегодня' хочу чтобы заголовок становился не 'Сегодня', а текущий день и месяц

Comment: меняйте значения в массиве, который привязан к спиннеру, после чего обновляйте адаптер: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`